# I want to fetch API with dynamic values but Mongoose is not taking value

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

```
let wid = req.params.wid;

let result = await model.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      windo_no: wid,
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: '$date'
  },
  {
    $match: {
      'date.date': "2022-09-09"
    }
  }
]);
```

Here it is not taking value of `wid` but when I `console.log(wid);`, it is giving value, here `wid` is `int` value and same for `date`, it is `string`.

I've also tried:

```
$match: { windo_no: { $eq: wid }
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question and provide some sample dataset? A [mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/) link would be helpful.

Comment: {
    "_id": "63256cf7ecae3111e53c50a1",
    "windo_no": 2,
    "services": []}this will be output if I write  windo_no: 2,

Comment: Why do you have the `unwind` and a 2nd `match` stage if you don't have a date field? have you tried removing those?

Comment: it is needed i have only show necessary output here

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
  'date.date':date2.toString()
```

for string

`windo_no: {$eq: +wid}` for int write + before dynamic value you want to give

Comment: Hi, if this belongs to your question add it there. You can edit your question.
If this is answer please read this [How to ask good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)